# How do I use a substring to find a dataframe that starts with specific characters?

Tags: r

I am trying to solve this problem where I need to use a substring to find how many games **START** with the characters "Yoshi" in a data frame.  We define the game name variable with vgsales$Name (the table is called vgsales.csv).  I do not understand how we would check a variable if it has Yoshi in it.

We are told to count the observations (the row so I assume it is `vgsales[, "Name"]`)

I don't have much for code, and I know the answer is 11 from looking at the table itself.

```
game <- substr(vgsales[,"Name"],1,5)
length(game["Yoshi"])
```

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of ways to solve this -

```
#1.
count1 <- sum(substr(vgsales$Name,1,5) == 'Yoshi')
#2.
count2 <- sum(startsWith(vgsales$Name, 'Yoshi'))
#3.
count3 <- sum(grepl('^Yoshi', vgsales$Name))
#4.
count4 <- length(grep('^Yoshi', vgsales$Name))
```

Comment: Yeah comparing answers with yours, your code is more simple.  I appreciate the answers!  I feel bad because I found the solution right after I posted it, even though what I put was different from yours.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I had an epiphany and solved it!

```
game <- substr(vgsales[,"Name"],1,5)
length(which(game == "Yoshi"))
```